# Get a list off all threads running on Android device

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Is it possible  to get a list of all threads currently running on an Android device?
I am using Android studio and I have created two Android projects.

In the first app I created a dummy threads.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    Thread t = new Thread("DummyTHREAD")
    {
        public void run() {
                while(true) {
                   // yield();
                }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

In the second app I want a thread list including the dummy thread from App one. I have tried already the following:

```
java.util.Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> myMap = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
```

Then I started the first app and debugged the second app afterwards, but this just show me the system threads and the main thread of my second application.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: A JVM can only see threads that are running inside it. Even if you had access to native tools that allow you to see native (OS) threads, there would still be no obvious way to map it to threads created inside currently running JVMs.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm asking because I'm trying to implement a thread enummeration covert channel. Do you know how such a covert channel should look like if threads are per app?